# Isolated Scope object not passing correctly from root (scope) controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to move objects values to isolate scope in a directive but the value is undefined

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pudv35c0/5/)

```
  <div>
            <input ng-model="title" type='text'/>
            <input ng-model="minDays" type='text'/>
            <input ng-model="maxDays" type='text'/>
            <week-days action="AddShift(week)" shiftPatterns = "shiftPatterns" style="display:inline-block"></week-days>

        </div>

        <div ng-repeat="shiftPattern in shiftPatterns">
            <input  type='text'ng-value="shiftPattern.title"></input>
            <input  type='text' ng-value="shiftPattern.minDays"></input>
            <input  type='text' ng-value="shiftPattern.maxDays"></input>
            <week-days selectedDays="shiftPattern" style="display:inline-block"></week-days>
        </div>

app.directive("weekDays", function(){
  return{
    restrict: "AEC",
     scope: {
      shiftPatterns: '=',
      selectedDays: '=shiftPattern',
      action: '&'

    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
       $scope.week = [{"name":"MON", "selected":false}  , {"name":"TUE", "selected":false}  , {"name":"WED", "selected":false}  , {"name":"THU", "selected":false} , {"name":"FRI", "selected":false}  , {"name":"SAT", "selected":false}  , {"name":"SUN", "selected":false} ];
       $scope.AddOrRemoveDay = function(day){
          day.selected = !day.selected
      };

    },
    template: "{{selectedDays}}{{shiftPatterns}}<div style='width:500px; display:inline'>"+
                "<div ng-repeat='day in week' ng-class=\"{true:'possibleDayStyle', false:'notPossibleDay'}[day.selected]\" ng-click='AddOrRemoveDay(day)'>"+
                    "{{day.name}}</div>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<button class='btnAddPossibleDays' ng-click='action({ week: week })'>Add</button>"
  }
});
```

I want to print the shiftPatterns and selected days but it is undefined
https://jsfiddle.net/pudv35c0/5/

Comment: look at your directive, it uses shiftPatterns, where as in your code, you are using =shiftPattern.

Comment: To pass the value of shiftPatterns, you must use `shift-patterns="shiftPatterns"`. There might be other problems, but I didn't go further. Same for selectedDays: `selected-days="..."`

Answer (score 1):

To pass the value of shiftPatterns, you must use shift-patterns="shiftPatterns". There might be other problems, but I didn't go further. Same for selectedDays: selected-days="..."